# How to use Compiled Typescript file.(ts) which is (.js) in another Project

Tags: html, angular

I want to use existing `angular(typescript)` project in another project which is in `JavaScript(.js)`. Is there any possible way of using compiled typescript files in another Project

for example Project-1 is in `Typescript` and Project-2 is in `JavaScript`.
I want to use or migrate Typescript to JavaScript without re writing whole Project. how to achieve this. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An angular application is about a couple of js files and index.html after the prod build. Typescript files are transpiled to javascript eventually.
Although it is technically possible, since the js files are not human readable, integrating the javascript code in hand with some other project would be insanely effortful, even nearly impossible.

[image]

What you can do easily is showing one application inside the other project's page etc.

If you look at the other way around, getting an Angular project to work with a pure javascript project would be easier however Angular CLI does not support something like this officially.